# How to log into website from iOS device?

Tags: networking, ios5

Someone I work with created a website that he wants to use to provide a service. They run a php script when the user taps Login that checks username/password/etc

Now I want to write an app that would allow logging in and also retrieving data, as one would on the website. How can I pass the login info from the iOS device to that PHP script that is run on the website? And after I'm logged in, how can I check and retrieve the data?

Do I need to ask him for an API?

Comment: obviously you need a webservice to communicate between the app and the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebsite.com/login.php"]];

NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user=myuser&pass=mypass"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```